# Variables in react props

Tags: reactjs

I have a data for the links in the form of array:

```
const FooterLinksData = [
        {
            link1: "Insolvers",
            link2: "How it works?",
            link5: "I'm looking for job",
            link4: "I'm looking to hire",
        },
    ];
```

In parent element:
In parent element props.num comes from another parent element having prop num set to a **number.**

```
<FooterLinks data={FooterLinksData[props.num]} num={props.num} />
```

The child element:

```
return (
        <a href="/" className="footer_link">
            {props.data.link1} {/* Instead of link 1 I want to make it dynamic */}
        </a>
       );
```

I want to make props.data.link1 dynamic so that I can put the props.num in there. Is there any way to do this. Please help.

Comment: what is `num`??

Comment: num is just a number

Comment: Apologies, your question is a bit confusing to answer. Can you please try to express what you are trying to achieve? Maybe show more of the code, or create a codesandbox example?

Comment: Why are you not passing `link1` to the child element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `linkX` when `num` is `X`, you could use template literals to create the correct string (link1, link2, etc).

```
<a href="/" className="footer_link">
  {props.data[`link${props.num}`]}
</a>
```

---

See also: [Computed Property Names (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) and [Bracket notation (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation)

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression in brackets `[]`, that will be computed and used as the property name.

> In the `object[property_name]` syntax, the `property_name` is just a string or Symbol. So, it can be any string, including `'1foo'`, `'!bar!'`, or even `' '` (a space).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the dynamic link number from the parent as a prop `dynamicLinkNum`

```js
return (
        <a href="/" className="footer_link">
            {props.data[props.dynamicLinkNum]}
        </a>
       );
```